# Linear Algebra - Orthogonal problem (from exam can I appeal this?)

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I have this problem :

Let $A=\{v_1,v_2....,v_k\}$ in $R^n$ while $2 \leq k$.

Prove if $A^\perp=(A-\{v_1\})^\perp$, then A is not linear independant.

**Please take a look at my solution since this is my answer from the exam and I think to appeal on this question, I'd like to hear your thoughts if I could appeal this.**

**My solution**

Lets assume that $A$ is linear independant.

We know that $$A^\perp=(A-\{v_1\})^\perp \rightarrow A^\perp = \{v_2,v_3,...,v_k\}^\perp$$

Using the definition we know that $A^\perp+A=R^n$ Therefore we can conclude:

$$A^\perp = \{v_2,v_3,...,v_k\}^\perp \rightarrow A^\perp=\{v_1,v_{k+1},v_{k+2}...v_n\}$$

It a known fact that for any $x \in A$ and $y \in A^\perp \rightarrow$ $x \bullet y = 0$

But we found that $v_1 \in A$ and also $v1 \in A^\perp$ which means that $v_1 \bullet v_1$ =0, and by theorem is can only be true if $v_1=0$ therefore $A$ is linear independant.

After reading my answer I found nothing wrong with it, I'll be glad if someone could tell me what's wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Assume $A$ is not linear independent, how do you deduce $v_1 \in A^\perp$?

Comment: @PetiteEtincelle Because $A^\perp$ is complete to $R^n$, We know that $A+A^\perp=R^n$

Comment: What is $v_{k+1}$? To be honest I'm having a very hard time understanding what you have written.

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick Edited, is it clear now?

Comment: You still haven't defined $v_{k+1}$.

Comment: I mean that $\{v_{k+1},v_{k+2},..\}$ complete to $R^n$. Meaning that $$A+A^\perp = \{v_1,v_2,...v_k,v_{k+1},v_{k+2},...v_n\} = R^n$$

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick Is it clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that all $v_i$ are non-zero.

Here is one example for the assumption that $A$ is not linearly independent: $v_1 = v_2 + v_3$.

In this case, obviously, $v_1 \in [ \{ v_2, v_3 \} ]$, i.e., $v_1 \not \in A^\perp$. Therefore, your first step is wrong.

Further, I'm quite positive that the original statement is wrong. I think that $A^\perp = (A - \{v_1\})^\perp$ implies that $v_1$ is a linear combination of other vectors in $A$ (specifically, that $A$ is not linearly independent).

The reason (not exactly a proof, but not far from it either) is simple. Assume that $v_2,\dots,v_k$ are linearly independent (if they are not, we can just remove some of those that depend on some others and nothing will change). So,
$$\dim A^\perp = n - \dim [A] = n - k$$
if and only if $A$ is linearly independent. However,
$$\dim (A - \{v_1\})^\perp = n - \dim [\{v_2,\dots,v_k\}] = n - (k - 1) = n - k + 1.$$

Comment: Sego, Your right, I mistyped the question I wrote that $A$ is linear independent instand of not linear independent, could you please take a look now? (I edited the question)

Comment: The basic idea seems fine now, albeit somewhat imprecise (it is, as others have pointed out, missing the definition of $v_i$ for $i > k$) and missing some explanations (for example, what Andreas just asked about in his comment). Also, this is wrong: $A^\perp=\{v_1,v_{k+1},v_{k+2}...v_n\}$. It should be $A^\perp=[\{v_1,v_{k+1},v_{k+2}...v_n\}]$ (you need a closure of $n-k+1$ linearly independent vectors, not just them).

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me as if you've assumed that all the $v_i$'s (the $v_1,\dots,v_k$ in the problem and also the $v_{k+1},v_{k+2},\dots$ that came from nowhere) are orthogonal to each other.  There's no justification for this assumption.

Comment: I edited, I meant that $\{v_{k+1},v_{k+2},..\}$ complete to $R^n$

Comment: I'm not sure that "complete to $R^n$" has a meaning, but in any case I don't see how your argument could work without an assumption of orthogonality.

Comment: By complete to $R^n$ I mean that $$A+A^\perp = \{v_1,v_2,...v_k,v_{k+1},v_{k+2},...v_n\} = R^n$$ Since we know that $$A+A^\perp = R^n$$ therefore $A^\perp$ complete $A$ to $R^n$ I'm sorry English is not my first language is it clear now?

Comment: OK, you've explained "complete" (usually called "spanning"), but I stand by my earlier comment that, without an additional assumption of orthogonality, your argument won't work.  Why, for example, should I believe that $v_1\in\{v_2,\dots,v_k\}^\bot$?

Comment: I'll tell you why (I think so), we assume $A$ is linear independent, we know that $A^\perp=\{v_2,v_3...v_k\}^\perp$ We know that $\{v_2,v_3,...v_k\}$ are also linear independent therefore we can conclude that $v1 \in A^\perp$ since $A^\perp$ must include all the vectors "left" inorder to span to $R^n$ since $A$ linear independant.

Comment: You've confirmed what I suspected; the last part of your comment (after "therefore") is wrong.  $A^\bot$ must include enough vectors so that, when combined with the vectors in $A$, they span $R^n$, but there's no reason why those vectors have to include $v_1$.